# When does a struct require a default constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, struct, default-constructor

I wrote a `struct` with custom constructor designed to be a data member of a class:

```
struct HP
{
    int max_hp;
    int hp;
    // HP(){}; it is required for the next class constructor function. Why?
    HP(int max_hp) {
        this->max_hp=max_hp;
        this->hp=max_hp;
    }
};

class Character
{
protected:
    HP hp;

    friend struct HP;

public:
    Character(int hp);
};
```

`Character` reports: `Error C2512: 'HP': no appropriate default constructor available`

```
Character::Character(int hp){
    this->hp = HP(hp);
}
```

Where did I implicitly initialize `HP` such that a default constructor is required? `inline`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All class members are initialized before entering the body of the constructor.

```cpp
Character::Character(int hp)
{ // already too late to initialize Character::hp
    this->hp = HP(hp); // this is an assignment
}
```

Without a `HP` default constructor, `Character(int hp);` cannot initialize its `hp` member unless it can provide arguments to the `HP` constructor, and the only way to forward the arguments to the `HP` constructor is with a [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Example:

```cpp
struct HP{
    int max_hp;
    int hp;
    HP(int max_hp): // might as well use member initializer list here as well
        max_hp(max_hp),
        hp(max_hp)
    {
        // no need for anything in here. All done in Member Initializer List
    }
};

class Character
{
protected:
    HP hp;

    friend struct HP; // not necessary. HP has no private members.

public:
    Character(int hp);
};

Character::Character(int hp):
        hp(hp)
{
}
```